# How to configure Rails to use the correct ActiveStorage storage service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, service, storage

I'm running Rails 6.3 on Ruby 2.7.2p137

My goal is to have a public S3 bucket and a private S3 bucket. I would like the public bucket so Rails will serve the S3 URL directly and avoid a redirect. And, once this is working, so I can put them in a CDN. And the private bucket for more secure files (realizing limited security through obscurity if the redirect URLs are served).

In my `config/storage.yaml` I have the following:

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

# Use rails credentials:edit to set the AWS secrets (as aws:access_key_id|secret_access_key)
amazon:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
    secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
    region: us-east-1
    bucket: <public-bucket-name>
    public: true

private:
    service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
    secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
    region: us-east-1
    bucket: <private-bucket-name (absolutely different from public name)>
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

in `config/environments/test.rb`:

```
config.active_storage.service = :test
```

in `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

In the models which will have attachments in the public service, I have the following (e.g.):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_one_attached :avatar
```

In production, I expect it to use the default storage service (:amazon) set in the configuration file.

For the attachments I want to store in the private bucket, I have (e.g.):

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_one_attached :spec, service: :private
```

However, when I upload the spec file (using direct upload) in `ProductsController#create` or `ProductsController#update`, the `active_storage_blobs` has a new row, but the `service_name` is `amazon` and I can confirm the file has been uploaded to the public bucket rather than the private bucket.

So, it appears that `service: :private` is completely ignored.

How can I configure this so files attached to the Product are uploaded to the :private service?